# Is it possible to define python function by pybind11?

Tags: python, function, printing, var, pybind11

How can I define python function by pybind11?

For example I have the following function:

```
def test(var):
    print(var)
```

is it possible to define this by pybind11?

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/utilities.html#evaluating-python-expressions-from-strings-and-files

Comment: I am familiar with this one. Is there another solution? I do not want to write a python program by using string.

Comment: AFAIK, to create a Python function object, you need a code object (byte code + metadata) that implements it. And to get that, you either need to compile Python source code, or load a already compiled bytecode (or I suppose generate it manually, which seems a bit masochistic, and likely to break over time, since the bytecode can and does change between releases).